# How to match a emoticon in sentence with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, emoticons

I'm using Python to process Weibo (a twitter-like service in China) sentences. 
There are some emoticons in the sentences, whose corresponding unicode are `\ue317` etc.
To process the sentence, I need to encode the sentence with gbk, see below:

```
 string1_gbk = string1.decode('utf-8').encode('gb2312')
```

There will be a `UnicodeEncodeError:'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\ue317'`

I tried `\\ue[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}`, but it did not work. How could I match these emoticons in sentences?

Comment: Is the data coming from Weibo in UTF-8 or in GB2312? Why can't you stick with the encoding of the data as given?

Comment: the data from weibo is encoded in utf-8, but I need to process the data with an opensource parser which could only process the sentence encoded with gbk. So I need to complete the transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
string1_gbk = string1.decode('utf-8').encode('gb2312', 'replace')
```

Should output ? instead of those emoticons.

[Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) - [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeEncodeError)

Comment: Thanks,it works, it replace there emoticons with a question mark.

Comment: I use the 'ignore' instead, it meets my requirement, thank you

Answer (score 4):

`'\ue317'` is not a substring of `u"asdasd \ue317 asad"` - it's human-readable unicode character representation, and can not be matched by regexp. regexp works with `repr(u'\ue317')`

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the backslash is a special escape character in regexp syntax. The following worked for me:

```
>>> test_str = 'blah blah blah \ue317 blah blah \ueaa2 blah ue317'
>>> re.findall(r'\\ue[0-9A-Za-z]{3}', test_str)
['\\ue317', '\\ueaa2']
```

Notice it doesn't erroneously match the `ue317` at the end, which has no preceding backslash. Obviously, use `re.sub()` if you wish to replace those character strings.

Comment: I tried this way, but it did not take effect in chinese sentence encoded with utf-8, I do not know the reason.

Comment: It's because `test_str` contains `\ue317`, not the unicode character often represented by `\ue317`

Comment: @NickODell, I've never had to deal with language encoding issues, but, if he were to attempt to replace those strings representing unicode characters using regexps (which is obviously sub-optimal given your answer above), would he first have to convert into something like iso-8859-1 in order to render them in that backslash-escaped format?

Comment: @Greg, Looks like [asyntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10890297/530160) tried to answer you, but doesn't have the comment everywhere privilege yet.