# How to find and count emoticons in a string using python?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

This topic has been addressed for text based emoticons at [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283681/regular-expressions-emoticons), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890261/how-to-match-a-emoticon-in-sentence-with-regular-expressions), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571103/capturing-emoticons-using-regular-expression-in-python). However, I would like to do something slightly different than matching simple emoticons. I'm sorting through tweets that contain the emoticons' icons. The following unicode information contains just such emoticons: [pdf](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf).

Using a string with english words that also contains any of these emoticons from the [pdf](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf), I would like to be able to compare the number of emoticons to the number of words.

The direction that I was heading down doesn't seem to be the best option and I was looking for some help. As you can see in the script below, I was just planning to do the work from the command line:

```
$cat <file containing the strings with emoticons> | ./emo.py
```

emo.py psuedo script:

```
import re
import sys

for row in sys.stdin:
    print row.decode('utf-8').encode("ascii","replace")
    #insert regex to find the emoticons
    if match:
       #do some counting using .split(" ")
       #print the counting
```

The problem that I'm running into is the decoding/encoding. I haven't found a good option for how to encode/decode the string so I can correctly find the icons. An example of the string that I want to search to find the number of words and emoticons is as follows:

"Smiley emoticon rocks![image] I like you[image]."

The challenge: **can you make a script that counts the number of words and emoticons in this string?** Notice that the emoticons are both sitting next to the words with no space in between.

Comment: Is using regexp a requirement here?

Comment: This is all pretty basic regex stuff, so… have you read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto), or, better, a third-party tutorial?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, there is no need to encode here at all. You're got a Unicode string, and the `re` engine can handle Unicode, so just use it.

A [character class](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) can include a range of characters, by specifying the first and last with a hyphen in between. And you can specify Unicode characters that you don't know how to type with `\U` escape sequences. So:

```
import re

s=u"Smiley emoticon rocks!\U0001f600 I like you.\U0001f601"
count = len(re.findall(ru'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s))
```

Or, if the string is big enough that building up the whole `findall` list seems wasteful:

```
emoticons = re.finditer(ru'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s)
count = sum(1 for _ in emoticons)
```

Counting words, you can do separately:

```
wordcount = len(s.split())
```

If you want to do it all at once, you can use an alternation group:

```
word_and_emoticon_count = len(re.findall(ru'\w+|[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s))
```

---

As @strangefeatures points out, Python versions before 3.3 allowed "narrow Unicode" builds. And, for example, most CPython Windows builds are narrow. In narrow builds, characters can only be in the range `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`. There's no way to search for these characters, but that's OK, because they're don't exist to search for; you can just assume they don't exist if you get an "invalid range" error compiling the regexp.

Except, of course, that there's a good chance that wherever you're getting your actual strings from, they're UTF-16-BE or UTF-16-LE, so the characters *do* exist, they're just encoded into surrogate pairs. And you want to match those surrogate pairs, right? So you need to translate your search into a surrogate-pair search. That is, convert your high and low code points into surrogate pair code units, then (in Python terms) search for:

```
(lead == low_lead and lead != high_lead and low_trail <= trail <= DFFF or
 lead == high_lead and lead != low_lead and DC00 <= trail <= high_trail or
 low_lead < lead < high_lead and DC00 <= trail <= DFFF)
```

You can leave off the second condition in the last case if you're not worried about accepting bogus UTF-16.

If it's not obvious how that translates into regexp, here's an example for the range `[\U0001e050-\U0001fbbf]` in UTF-16-BE:

```
(\ud838[\udc50-\udfff])|([\ud839-\ud83d].)|(\ud83e[\udc00-\udfbf])
```

Of course if your range is small enough that `low_lead == high_lead` this gets simpler. For example, the original question's range can be searched with:

```
\ud83d[\ude00-\ude50]
```

One last trick, if you don't actually know whether you're going to get UTF-16-LE or UTF-16-BE (and the BOM is far away from the data you're searching): Because no surrogate lead or trail code unit is valid as a standalone character or as the other end of a pair, you can just search in both directions:

```
(\ud838[\udc50-\udfff])|([\ud839-\ud83d][\udc00-\udfff])|(\ud83e[\udc00-\udfbf])|
([\udc50-\udfff]\ud838)|([\udc00-\udfff][\ud839-\ud83d])|([\udc00-\udfbf]\ud83e)
```

Comment: I had to change your r' to u' as re.findall(u'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s.decode('utf-8')), which then correctly finds the emoticons. Thanks @abarnert!

Comment: @simplyclimb: Yeah, you need the `u'…'`—and the `s` variable should _also_ be a unicode string. (For some reason, I assumed you were using Python 3, but looking at you're question, it's obviously 2.x.) But you still want the `r`. In this case, dropping it happens to not matter, because a Python stirng literal will interpret the escape sequence `\U0001f600` the exact same way as the `re` engine would… But it's a good idea to always use raw strings for regexps unless you have a specific reason not to, instead of studying each regexp to figure out whether you need a raw string or not.

Comment: The re `ur'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]'` fails to compile on some Python builds less than 3.3 (I think narrow builds - ie `sys.maxunicode == 0xffff`), with a "bad character range" error.

Comment: @strangefeatures: Yeah, IIRC that's considered a "wontfix" bug in the `re` library because the 3.3 Unicode changes made it irrelevant, and because there's no easy fix with UTF-16. I'll update the answer to explain, but no one will like the solution…

Comment: @strangefeatures: (Also, I believe we were supposed to be getting `regex` to replace `re` in 2.7/3.2, which could have handled this for you, but then it got deferred to 3.3, then 3.4, and then indefinitely…)

Answer (score 5):

My solution includes the [`emoji`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji/) and [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) modules. The regex module supports recognizing grapheme clusters (sequences of Unicode codepoints rendered as a single character), so we can count emojis like  ‍‍‍   once, although it consists of 4 emojis.

```
import emoji
import regex

def split_count(text):
    emoji_counter = 0
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', text)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):
            emoji_counter += 1
            # Remove from the given text the emojis
            text = text.replace(word, '') 

    words_counter = len(text.split())

    return emoji_counter, words_counter
```

Testing:

```
line = "hello ‍ emoji hello ‍‍‍ how are  you today"
counter = split_count(line)
print("Number of emojis - {}, number of words - {}".format(counter[0], counter[1]))
```

Output:

```
Number of emojis - 5, number of words - 7
```

Comment: `UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):` error

Comment: Easier: `for word in data: if emoji.is_emoji(word): ...`

Comment: Even better, you can collapse the whole for loop: `emoji_counter = sum(emoji.is_emoji(word) for word in data)`. If you really need to count words too, like OP, you subtract `emoji_counter` from `word_counter`, no need to do multiple replacements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read unicode characters outside the ascii range, don't convert *into* the ascii range.  Just leave it as unicode and work from there (untested):

```
import sys

count = 0
emoticons = set(range(int('1f600',16), int('1f650', 16)))
for row in sys.stdin:
    for char in row:
        if ord(char) in emoticons:
            count += 1
print "%d emoticons found" % count
```

Not the best solution, but it should work.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution using `re`:

```
import re
text = "your text with emojis"
em_count = len(re.findall(r'[^\w\s,.]', text))
print(em_count)
```

Comment: Could you explain your code only answer?

Comment: Your code is non-obvious: how does the regex pattern work, what does `findall` do (link to the docs). That's the bare minimum you could do to explain your answer

Comment: We are not learning python here. There are enough sources and official docs explaining those functions. Also, there are docs teach you regular expression