# Python 2.7 range regex matching unicode emoticons

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode, emoticons

How to count the number of unicode emoticons in a string using python 2.7 regex? I tried the first answer posted for this question. But it has been showing invalid expression error.

re.findall(u'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s.decode('utf-8')) is not working and showing invalid expression error

[How to find and count emoticons in a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149186/how-to-find-and-count-emoticons-in-a-string-using-python)

"Thank you for helping out (Emoticon1) Smiley emoticon rocks!(Emoticon2)"

Count : 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to using a "narrow build" of Python 2. That is, if you fire up your interpreter, you'll find that `sys.maxunicode == 0xffff` is `True`.

[This site](http://haypo-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/unicode.html) has a few interesting notes on wide builds of Python (which are commonly found on Linux, but not, as the link suggests, on OS X in my experience). These builds use UCS-4 internally to encode characters, and as a result seem to have saner support for higher range Unicode code points, such as the ranges you are talking about. Narrow builds apparently use UTF-16 internally, and as a result encode these higher code points using "surrogate pairs". I presume this is the reason you see a `bad character range` error when you try and compile this regular expression.

The only solution I know is to switch to a python version >= 3.3 which [no longer has the wide/narrow distinction](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/#id5) if you can, or [install a wide Python build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25111521/1711188)