# How to install python on Mac with wide-build

Tags: python, macos

I found that Python on my Mac build with narrow-build which will raise character range error when i use the re model.

So I want to install the wide-build in my Mac.So how can I install Python with wide-build on Mac?

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem? Character range errors can just be a badly formatted regex

Comment: Can you show a simple version of what is failing and the traceback you get?

Answer (score 6):

If you really need a "wide build" of Python 2 on OS X to support Unicode code points above `0xffff`, you'll probably have to build it yourself from source.  Most distributions for OS X that I am aware of use the default "narrow build"; one exception is [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) which does support a wide-build variant:

```
sudo port install python27 +ucs4
```

To build Python yourself from source, download and unpack [the latest Python source tarball](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and set appropriate configure arguments for your situation.  The key one is `--enable-unicode=ucs4`.  For example, a minimal configuration might be:

```
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tgz
tar xf ./Python-2.7.8.tgz
cd ./Python-2.7.8
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4 --prefix=/path/to/install MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
make
make install
cd
/path/to/install/bin/python2.7
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug  3 2014, 22:27:28)
> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import sys
> >>> sys.maxunicode
> 1114111
> ```

As noted by Jason, current Python 3 releases always support all Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4):

If using Python3 upgrade to the latest version. In 3.3 and later:

> The distinction between narrow and wide Unicode builds is dropped.

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/