# sre_constants.error: bad character range when building python from source code

Tags: docker, python-2.7, debian

I am setting a Docker service for bacnet using Debian10 and python2.7. When I install python by the command apt-get install -y python-pip my application works fine. Howerver when I try installing python2.7 by downloading and extracting, the docker service throws the next error:

```
  File "src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bacpypes.core import run as runbacpypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bacpypes/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from . import local
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bacpypes/local/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import object
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bacpypes/local/object.py", line 140, in <module>
    local_name_re = re.compile(u"^" + PN_LOCAL + u"$", re.UNICODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Portion of the Dockerfile that causes the error:

- Command apt-get install -y python-pip that works

```
FROM debian:10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip
```

- Download and extract python (causes the error)

```
FROM debian:10

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gcc make openssl libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
  && apt-get clean
WORKDIR /tmp/

# Build python from source
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.18
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && tar --extract -f Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && cd ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION/ \
  && ./configure --with-ensurepip=install --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make && make install \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION*
```

Rest of the Dockerfile content (bacnet dependencies):

```
ARG PAHO_MQTT_VERSION=1.6.1
ADD bacnet/source-code-dependencies/paho_mqtt-$PAHO_MQTT_VERSION/ ./paho_mqtt-$PAHO_MQTT_VERSION/
RUN cd ./paho_mqtt-$PAHO_MQTT_VERSION/ \
  && python setup.py install \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./paho_mqtt-$PAHO_MQTT_VERSION*

# RUN pip install bacpypes==0.18.0
ARG BACPYPES_VERSION=0.18.0
ADD bacnet/source-code-dependencies/bacpypes-$BACPYPES_VERSION/ ./bacpypes-$BACPYPES_VERSION/
RUN cd ./bacpypes-$BACPYPES_VERSION/ \
  && pip install bacpypes-0.18.0-py2-none-any.whl \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./bacpypes*

WORKDIR /bacnet
ADD bacnet/site-packages ./site-packages
ADD bacnet/src ./src

WORKDIR /bacnet
ENV PYTHONPATH=/bacnet/src/Bacnet
CMD ["python", "src/main.py"]
```

What the reason for this error when building python from source code could be? I've tried different versions of python 2.7 and it always happens.

I have read in different threads the reason for the *sre_constants.error: bad character range* is caused by placing a hyphen between characters but no idea why just the way installing the same python version makes it happen or not.

Reproducing the procedure without Docker the same error happens, I printed the argument from the compile instruction where the error happens (local_name_re = re.compile(u"^" + PN_LOCAL + u"$", re.UNICODE)) getting:

u"^([A-Za-z\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02ff\u0370-\u037d\u037f-\u1fff\u200c-\u200d\u2070-\u218f\u2c00-\u2fef\u3001-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\ufffd\U00010000-\U000effff_:0-9]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]|[-\*~.!$&'()*+,;=/?#@%]))(([-A-Za-z\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02ff\u0370-\u037d\u037f-\u1fff\u200c-\u200d\u2070-\u218f\u2c00-\u2fef\u3001-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\ufffd\U00010000-\U000effff_0-9\xb7\u0300-\u036f\u203f-\u2040.:]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]|[-\*~.!$&'()*+,;=/?#@%]))*([-A-Za-z\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02ff\u0370-\u037d\u037f-\u1fff\u200c-\u200d\u2070-\u218f\u2c00-\u2fef\u3001-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\ufffd\U00010000-\U000effff_0-9\xb7\u0300-\u036f\u203f-\u2040:]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]|[-\_~.!$&'()*+,;=/?#@%])))?$"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python on Mac with wide-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111521/how-to-install-python-on-mac-with-wide-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimming off pieces of the regex easily reveals that the problematic expression is

```
>>> re.compile(u"^([\U00010000-\U000effff])")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tripleee/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/tripleee/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

<del>It looks like Python 2.7 out of the box simply cannot accept a Unicode character range outside the BMP.</del>

Depending on how Python is built, Python 2 needed special options to be used at build time to support this feature. Going back in time, it was unavailable in the `re` library because of a bug even when you had a "wide build".

https://bugs.python.org/issue12749

The Debian `python` source package [reveals](https://sources.debian.org/src/python2.7/2.7.18-13.1/debian/rules/#L331) how exactly it is compiled but probably your easiest way forward is to simply install the precompiled package.

[Quick Duck Duck Going](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111521/how-to-install-python-on-mac-with-wide-build) suggests that `--enable-unicode=ucs4` might be useful if you really need to compile your own version.

(For brief background, the `\u0123` syntax specifies Unicode characters inside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), i.e. code points with a value less than or equal to 0xFFFF, which can be represented within 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes, and thus four hex digits after the lowercase `\u`. Code points outside this range require the uppercase U `\U00012345` syntax with eight hex digits, which internally requires a representation with room for more than 2 bytes per code point, i.e. a "wide build".)

Comment: Thanks! adding --enable-unicode=ucs4 for the python building configuration solved the probem